# Text input context menu still showing on Android after apply contextMenuHidden

Tags: react-native

I'm facing an issue on TextInput's contextMenuHidden on Android, IOS works well not showing the context menu though.

```
<TextInput style={styles.input} contextMenuHidden={true} />
```

I did tried the view component solution:

```
removeClippedSubviews={true}
```

However, the behaviour came back, after I delete the whole text input -> retype the text -> double tap (shows back context menu)

Not sure if anyone experienced this before, but need some advice/suggestion for Android case, must I create a custom native ui component instead?